# How do I add information to a neighbouring cell if there is specific text in an existing cell?

Tags: excel, gis

I'm working with 311 datasets. I have monthly spreadsheets for a specific municipality with over 10,000 entries per sheet.

The columns in the datasheet provide details such as call description, time of call, date of call and the City Ward the call originated from.

Problem is that the spreadsheets only give the Ward number, i.e.:

```
creation_date   | ward  | call_description |    call_type

01-Jan-15   | Ward 4    | Calendar to be Mailed |   Solid Waste Collection
```

I have a separate spreadsheet that assigns shape coordinates for the respective ward:

```
OBJECTID    | DESCRIPTIO    | WARD_NUM  | WARDNUMTEX    | SHAPE_Length |    SHAPE_Area

4   | XXXXX |4  | Ward 4    | 19871.78596   | 16418739.66
```

What I want to do is create a formula that when it sees `Ward 4` in the one column, the `SHAPE_Length` and `SHAPE_Area` are assigned in the corresponding cell in the next column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel vlookup help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381620/excel-vlookup-help)

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `vlookup()`.

Assuming that your tab with the shape coordinates is called `wardinfo` and that it starts in cell `A1`. Also assuming that your datasheets data starts in `A1`, meaning the `ward number` is in column `B`, your `vlookup()` to get the `Shape_Length` will be:

```
=vlookup(B1, wardinfo!C:F, 3, false)
```

And to get the `Shape_Area`:

```
=vlookup(B1, wardinfo!C:F, 4, false)
```

Just stick those in a new column on the same row and then copy them down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a VLOOKUP formula ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1 ), something like

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!D:F,2,FALSE)
```

Where `B2` is the cell in the ward column your looking up, `D:F` is the range of columns you're using in the other sheet as a database (`D` is the column in the other sheet that has the `Ward 4` index string, the rest of the columns you need should be to the right of that), and `2` is the column number that has the value you want to use as the result of the lookup (in that example, `D` is column 1, `E` would be column 2, probably `SHAPE_Length` and `F` would be column 3, probably `SHAPE_Area`).

You would put the formula a second time specifying column 3 for the second piece of info. The formula would go in the cell where you want the answer.